# How to use different unauthorized url for different roles in apache shiro

Tags: java, jsf-2.2, shiro

I have been trying to assign different unauthorized url for different roles in url section of shiro.ini file for a web application but it seems I am not able to do it.Below is the code that I have tried.

**shiro.ini file**

```
[main]

    authc1 = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter
    authc2 = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter

    authc1.loginUrl = /login.xhtml
    authc2.loginUrl = /secLoginPage.xhtml 


[urls]
    /login.xhtml = authc1
    /secLoginPage.xhtml  = authc2
    /testapp/** = authc1, roles[admin,unauthorizedUrl=/adminAuthPage.xhtml]
    /userfld/**=authc2,roles[user,unauthorizedUrl=/abortPage.xhtml]
    /** = authc1
    /** = authc2
```

After login to the application its redirect to authorized page with error `Error 401: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 401`.

This error occurred after I added `unauthorizedUrl=/adminAuthPage.xhtml`.
If there is any mistake in code please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about you make a single unauthorized page that acts like a entry point now on his page redirect to required pages

403.jsp

```
<shiro:hasRole name="admin">
    <c:redirect url="adminAuthPage.xhtml"/>
</shiro:hasRole>

<shiro:hasRole name="user">
    <c:redirect url="abortPage.xhtml"/>
</shiro:hasRole>
```

Or better if you just want admin has another page then

```
 <shiro:hasRole name="admin">
        <c:redirect url="adminAuthPage.xhtml"/>
 </shiro:hasRole>
<shiro:lacksRole name="admin">
    <c:redirect url="abortPage.xhtml"/>
</shiro:lacksRole>
```

Comment: But is there any way to do it by shiro ini mapping. If find any solution using shiro.ini file mapping please share

Comment: I followed documentation and source code but I am unable to find such a mapping. May be you can raise a improvement request with developers.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this is the way it should be done, you basically want to add a permission inside the roles.

http://shiro.apache.org/web.html

this

/testapp/** = authc1, roles[admin,unauthorizedUrl=/adminAuthPage.xhtml]

should be:

/testapp/** = authc1, roles[admin], perms["admin:*:*"]

Comment: This is what i tried but it's not working,                                                              /testapp/** = authc1, roles[admin],perms["admin:unauthorizedUrl=/adminAuthPage.xhtml"]
/userfld/**=authc2,roles[user],perms["user:unauthorizedUrl=/abortPage.xhtml"]